# I cant open Intellij 2021.3.1 after installing

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I downloaded Intellij from JetBrains website. When I try to start the app from cmd by idea.bat a have the next weird message about some licence crack:

```
C:\Program Files\IntelliJ IDEA 2021.3.1\bin>idea.bat


 ====================================================
 =======        Jetbrains License Crack       =======
 =======           https://zhile.io           =======
 ====================================================

 @See: https://zhile.io/2018/08/17/jetbrains-license-server-crack.html

 @Version: 3.2.0, @Build Date: 2020-04-10


Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at java.instrument/sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndStartAgent(InstrumentationImpl.java:513)
    at java.instrument/sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndCallPremain(InstrumentationImpl.java:525)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at fuck_the_regulations_v320.en.b(en.java)
    at fuck_the_regulations_v320.dH.premain(dH.java)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    ... 8 more
*** java.lang.instrument ASSERTION FAILED ***: "result" with message agent load/premain call failed at ./src/java.instrument/share/native/libinstrument/JPLISAgent.c line: 422
FATAL ERROR in native method: processing of -javaagent failed, processJavaStart failed
```

As I read on forums before the problem is often in idea.exe.vmoptions file. So here it is:

```
-Xms128m
-Xmx750m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=512m
-XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50
-XX:CICompilerCount=2
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
-XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow
-ea
-Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false
-Djdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes=""
-Djdk.attach.allowAttachSelf=true
-Djdk.module.illegalAccess.silent=true
-Dkotlinx.coroutines.debug=off
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have a cracked version of IntelliJ IDEA installed. Try deleting the IDE [configuration directory](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/directories-used-by-the-ide-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs.html#config-directory).

If that doesn't help reinstall the IDE from https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download to an empty directory.

Answer (score 1):

Look for .jetbrains in C:\Users\Public and remove it.

Answer (score 0):

To remove crack error in Linux you have to open
`/.config/JetBrains/PhpStorm2021.3/phpstorm64.vmoptions`
and comment line with `.jetbrains/jetbrains-agent-v3.2.0.de72.619`